# Can I make surfing safer through VM + CentOS 6.0 on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: security, centos

My Windows 7 machine was recently infected with some trojans via Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Is it safer to browse using the VMware Player + CentOS 6.0 and use Firefox inside CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you snapshot your virtual machine, you can do whatever you want on it.  Then when you are done, you return it to it's previous state by restoring from the snapshot.

Yes, this would increase security, but it would not make it perfect (no such thing).

Another safe answer is to boot/run CentOS from a Live distribution CD/DVD.  Then restart the computer when you are done with your browsing session.

Comment: How can I snapshot my virtual machine if I only have vmware player. When I boot from CentOS DVD, it is possible that I can install software? For example, firefox + adobe PDF + adobe flash player etc.

Comment: There are Live distributions of Linux (CentOS) that already have these tools preinstalled on the DVD/CDRom.  There really isn't a need to install them on the computer, they run from the DVD/CDRom, then when you turn off the computer, you leave no trace at all.  Find a sample here: http://distrowatch.com/6807

Comment: Q1> my machine is installed with Win7 64bit. Which version of CentOS Live version I should use? 32bit or 64bit. Q2> When I reboot my machine from DVD and run the CentOS Live, does it affect my current Win7 system. The laptop is not my property and I really don't want to mess it up. thank you

Comment: As you won't be using Windows7 while you are using the live version of CentOS, which version of Windows that is on your box won't matter.  If you don't know what CPU is in the box, go with a 32 bit version.

Comment: Intel Core(TM) i7-2760QM. So basically you said that the LIVE DVD will not change any boot info on my machine. is that correct?

Comment: You will need to tell the machine to boot from the DVD first (you may have to make a change in the laptops BIOS).  Do whatever surfing you want to do, then turn everything off.  If the DVD drive is empty when you boot back up the computer will boot from the next device in BIOS (typically the hard drive).  The whole point of a live Distro is to sample the OS before making changes on your computer.  It is designed NOT to effect what is already installed.

Comment: The Link you gave me for the LIVECD doesn't work anymore

Comment: Use Google and put in the following:

live Distribution CentOS 6.0

I'm sure there will be plenty of links that will get you to a download of CentOS.

Comment: they all required to use bit torrent to download